# Видимость функций

Tags: функции, perl

Достался в наследство некий движок, в котором, при парсинге шаблонов, происходит в том числе и следующее:

```
$result =~ s/(sub:(\w[\w\d]+\(.*?\));)/eval(caller().'::'.$2)/gsme;
```

Смысл в том, что в шаблоне вот такие конструкции заменяются на возврат соответствующей функции (условно):

```
<ul>sub:get_my_list(level=>2);<ul>
```

Речь сейчас не о кривости/некривости подхода (переписывать движок не планируется), и не о кривости самого регекспа (а она есть). А о том, как скрыть функции в вызывающем модуле. Потому как мало ли что кому взбредёт в голову в шаблон впихнуть, это совсем неправильно. Нужно спрятать все функции, которым там не место.

Подход в лоб - воспользоваться [`Sub::Private`](http://search.cpan.org/~pmakholm/Sub-Private-0.01/lib/Sub/Private.pm) & co. Но хочется наоборот, сделать вообще все функции приватными, КРОМЕ тех, для которых видимость за пределами модуля указана явно. Например, пройтись по typeglob и... Что "и"? Это вообще реально?

Comment: определяйте через хеш.

Comment: Это значит, что при создании новой функции её нужно будет руками заносить в этот хэш... Лучше бы, чтобы признак был уже при объявлении (копаю в сторону use attributes). Или вообще вынести их в отдельный модуль и проверять caller.